# What is the the SIMPLEST Typescript project in Visual Studio?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains several projects. Some of them are just TS files that I want to be turned into JS. That's it. The actual serving of the files is handled by other projects.

So far I'm creating full-fledged Web App projects, but that creates a **huge** project file, in the old project format.

What would the **minimum** project file look like, **in the new project format**? Ideally, I would like to have something this simple:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConvertTypeScriptFilesToJavaScript>true</ConvertTypeScriptFilesToJavaScript>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there anything like this?